# Помогите понять, где ошибка у меня в создании мешка слов

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Создаю вручную мешок слов. 
Вот функция для его создания:

```
def my_bag_of_words(text, words_to_index, dict_size):
    """
        text: a string
        dict_size: size of the dictionary

        return a vector which is a bag-of-words representation of 'text'
    """
    result_vector = np.zeros(dict_size)
    sentence_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text_prepare(text))
    attributes = []
    for i, k in words_to_index.items():
      while len(attributes)<=dict_size:
        attributes.append(i)
    for i in sentence_tokens: 
      for k in attributes:
        if i==k:
          result_vector[attributes.index(i)]=+1

    return result_vector
```

Функция возвращает 1, если слово в тексте есть в атрибутах и 0 - если его нет.

Проверяю эту функцию:

```
def test_my_bag_of_words():
    words_to_index = {'hi': 0, 'you': 1, 'me': 2, 'are': 3}
    examples = ['hi how are you']
    answers = [[1, 1, 0, 1]]
    for ex, ans in zip(examples, answers):
        if (my_bag_of_words(ex, words_to_index, 4) != ans).any():
          print(my_bag_of_words(ex, words_to_index, 4))
          return "Wrong answer for the case: '%s'" % ex
    return 'Basic tests are passed.'
print(test_my_bag_of_words())
```

Результат:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
Wrong answer for the case: 'hi how are you'
```

Если функция правильно создана, должно вывести:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1]
Basic tests are passed
```

Т. е. после увеличение первого элемента массива на 1, функция далее прекращает работу. 
Помогите пжл понять, в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Для начала предлагаю оптимизировать генерацию атрибутов:

```
attributes = list(words_to_index.keys())
```

А затем упростить последнюю часть кода:

```
for i in sentence_tokens:
    result_vector[attributes.index(i)] = int(i in attributes)
```

В таком случае, ответ будет таким: `answers = [[1, 0, 1, 1]]`, потому что отсутствующее в словаре слово *how* находится на второй позиции.